# How to know that fitToView() has finished completely

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I want to know that fitToView() finished completely.
Some program procedures do not work after fitToView() without setTimeout().
For example, the following code not work.

```
const dbid = [1141]
this.viewer.select(dbid)
this.viewer.fitToView(dbid, viewer.model)
zoom() //This will not work

//code from: 
function zoom (){
    var nav = viewer.navigation
    var pos = nav.getPosition()
    var target = nav.getTarget()
    var viewdir = new THREE.Vector3()
    viewdir.subVectors (pos, target).normalize()
    // zooms out by 100 along the view direction
    viewdir.multiplyScalar (1000)
    pos.add(viewdir)
    nav.setPosition(pos)
}
```

The following code work well.

```
this.viewer.fitToView(dbid, viewer.model)
setTimeout(function(){
    zoom() //This will work fine
}, 2000)
```

However, I don't want to use the setTimeout as much as possible.
Is there a way to know that fitToView () is finished completely?

Comment: Hi, I'm checking with our engineers if there is an event that gets launched at the time the fittoView finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use version 3.2.1 of the viewer a new event `Autodesk.Viewing.CAMERA_TRANSITION_COMPLETED`, it will be fired while following transitions are finished:

Go Home transition
Focus / Fit to View transition
Restore State transition
Named Views transition
Any other camera transitions

// Hook the event

```
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.CAMERA_TRANSITION_COMPLETED, function(){
console.log('camera is no longer moving');
```

});

// Trigger an action that will move the camera and fire the event

```
viewer.fitToView();
```

You can see more about the Viewer Version changes here. 
https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/overview/changelog/3.2.1/